# Retrieve image with Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm a newbie in Django, and I want to ask how to fetch images with Rest Api for Django.

Currently I have a model with an ImageField and I have no trouble uploading images,  or fetching the json for my item but when it comes to fetching it I don't have any clue how. I save the images in src\image\ inside the django app root folder. 
How do i fetch the image with an url like: localhost:8080/src/image/image1.jpg?

Answer (score 1):

Please, include your urls.py.

Do you have MEDIA_ROOT correctly configured? This is the location where your files are stored/uploaded.

But I assume you'd need to specify endpoint for your media files.

something like this :

```
from django.views.static import serve

urlpattenrs = [
     url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

After that, `path` is the location of your file which you used to store it ( relative to MEDIA_ROOT) .

You can now fetch your files using `media` endpoint + location of your file in MEDIA_ROOT directory ( you can call the endpoint like you want, i like `media` )